Deleted User - can their content be recovered?
Unfortunately we have deleted the user account for an ex-member of staff and all the content that they had put on the website has disappeared. We aren't sure who deleted the account, we assume that they picked the option 'delete all' rather than transfer content to another user.
Is there anyway to recover this information as the user didn't make a backup of the information anywhere else - or is the delete permanent?
Hoping this is possible :)

We have been able to download a number of Assets the staff member uploaded (Word & pdf) documents so not all has been lost.

I'm not certain, but you may find that the deleted entries are still available under 'trashed'


We aren't sure who deleted the account

This doesn't help you now, but in future you may want to limit the number of users who can administer user accounts.

Thanks Seth, we suspect we know who it was but without an audit function we can't be sure. We have reiterated that content creators aren't to be deleted.

If your hosting retains backups, this would have been a database specific change. You may be able to notate any changes made in the CMS that you wish to keep, and roll back to a backup of the site. Then disable the user properly. Best of luck!
